# Why Jquery $(#); doesn't work but Javascript document.getElementById works fine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of fully functioning codes in Javascript with "document.getElementById". But when I change it to Jquery, it doesn't work (and there are no errors).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style></style>
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    function formChk(){
    var success=true;
    var types = ["Western","Chinese","Local","Beverage"];
    var nameTxtBox=$("#name"); <!--This doesn't work-->
    var picturesTxtBox=document.getElementById("pictures"); <!--This works fine-->
```

The corresponding id="name" and id="pictures" are in the codes below:

```
<p><input type="text" id="name" name="name"></p>
<p><input type="text" id="pictures" name="pictures"></p>
```

There are no error messages in the console. However, the code doesn't run as per it's supposed to. This entire code is supposed to perform a form validation check - if the user input is left empty, it should throw an error message. However, when I change the "getElementById" to JQuery $(#);, the form validation doesn't work.

Why does this happen?? Isn't $(#); the exact equivalent of document.getElementById?

Comment: $ works on document ready.

Comment: "*There are no error messages in the console. However, the code doesn't run as per it's supposed to*" how is it supposed to work? Perhaps *it does* and it finds the element properly, but you are not using it correctly afterwards.

Comment: "Isn't $(#); the exact equivalent of document.getElementById?" - no, they return different things. Jquery returns a jquery object, the non-jquery one obviously does not return a jquery object... It sounds like you are probably therefore not using the jquery object correctly if you're not aware of this difference. Sadly you haven't showed us this code so we can't be sure.

Comment: Try placing your script before the `</body>` end tag.. It looks like you have it in the header, the document won't be ready yet.

Comment: "*Why does this happen?? Isn't $(#); the exact equivalent of document.getElementById?*" well...yes and no. It *would* lookup an element and if you use the CSS ID selector (`#`) it *would* look it up by the ID. However, saying they are "equivalent" can be a stretch. It's closer to `document.querySelectorAll()` where you can also give a CSS selector for a lookup. The two are still not the same - the jQuery lookup will return you a result set wrapped in a jQuery object, while a plain JS lookup returns you the raw DOMElements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("#name")` return a jQuery object not an Element object like `document.getElementById("pictures");` to return a Element object you need to get the Element object from the jQuery object

```
$("#name")[0]
```

Comment: And `$("#name").get(0)` as well.

Answer (score 6):

*Isn't $(#); the exact equivalent of document.getElementById?*

Absolutely not, they return very different elements, `jQuery` returns a

> collection of matched elements either found in the DOM based on passed argument(s) or created by passing an HTML string.

[Jquery() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

While `document.getElementById()` returns

> An Element object describing the DOM element object matching the specified ID, or null if no matching element was found in the document.

[document.getElementById() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

If for compatibility with your previous code you have to access the Element object from the jQuery collection, you can use the array notation.

So if the selector matches a single element, like an id, you can do

```
let el = $('#selector')[0];
```

To mimic the behaviour of `document.getElementById()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to get the value of #name it would be

`$("#name").val()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#fileUpload').val('');
```

We have to pass the value inside the val().